# FTP on the express-fileupload on node js

Tags: node.js, express

I just want to upload the file on the UNIX server path via UI screen. I have used express-fileupload module to do so on node js.

**App.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);
    const upload = require("express-fileupload");

    app.use(upload());

    console.log("Server Started");

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    }
    )

    app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    if (req.files) {
        //console.log(req.files);
        const file = req.files.filename;
        const filename = file.name;

        file.mv("./upload/" + filename, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("error occured");
        }
        else {
            res.send("Done");
        }
        })
    }
    })
```

The above code helped me to upload the file to the local directory. Need a help to upload the file to FTP path. Any help would be appreciated.

GitHub Repository : https://github.com/nandy2013/express-fileupload-node-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!

PF the complete code on the github!

https://github.com/nandy2013/uploadFileOnFTP-express-fileupload